# Error:method readString in class StdIn cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, string

Error:method readString in class StdIn cannot be applied to given types
required:no arguments
Found:java.lang.String
reason:autual and formal argument list differ in length

How do I fix the bug?Please help!

```
public class Subset {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    RandomizedQueue<String> test = new RandomizedQueue<String>();
    for (int i=1;i<=k;i++) {
        String s=StdIn.readString(args[i]);
        test.enqueue(s);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        StdOut.println(test.dequeue());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: StdIn is not in the standard library. What is it?

Comment: @Joni It's in my own java library.StdIn and StdOut is ok.

Comment: The error is saying you're not using your library correctly. You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. That is, you're calling readString with a string parameter, but it does not accept any parameters.

Comment: @Joni Oh,I try it,it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [System.in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) and [System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) instead of StdIn and StdOut, e.g.

`System.out.println("Hello World!");`

Comment: @luojiebin could you please post the method declaration of your readString function? The error message claims that you're passing an argument where there shouldn't be one, e.g. `StdIn.readString();`

Comment: @I found the error reason.It's because StdIn.readString() can't accept argument.Thanks